# navegar pelos elementos filhos

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de saber como fazer um loop para navegar por todos os elementos filhos?

De preferência código em JQuery, acredito que seja algo com `next()`, `children()`,`find()`....

Answer (score 11):

Há várias formas de fazer isso. Você pode utilizar o `children` ou o `find`, opcionalmente usando algum seletor mais específico. Para percorer os elementos, você pode usar o `each`.

```
// percorre todos os filhos
$(elem).children().each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
});

// percorre todos os filhos
$(elem).find("> *").each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
});

// percorre todos os li's filhos
$(elem).children("li").each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
});

// percorre todos os li's filhos
$(elem).find("> li").each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Acredito que utilizar o `children` seja a melhor opção, pois fica mais claro o que você quer fazer e ele não irá percorrer todos os elementos abaixo do elemento pai a procura dos que fechem com o seletor como o `find` faz.

Comment: você está utilizando a seleção deste jeito `> li`, isso é para indicar que você quer os filhos de li e não mais abaixo, é isso?

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Isso mesmo. Com o `>` eu garanto que ele vá pegar apenas os elementos imediatamente abaixo do elemento pai.

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode usar o [Each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) do jquery

http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
<ul id="column1">
   <li rel="1">Info</li>
   <li rel="2">Info</li>
   <li rel="3">Info</li>
</ul>
<ul id="column2">
   <li rel="4">Info</li>
   <li rel="5">Info</li>
   <li rel="6">Info</li>
</ul>
<ul id="column3">
   <li rel="7">Info</li>
   <li rel="8">Info</li>
   <li rel="9">Info</li>
</ul>


$('ul li').each(function(i) {

});
```

Comment: considerando que elemento DOM é um objeto, e eu posso percorrer ele com each, posso percorrer também um array?

Comment: Você pode utilizar o FOREACH do JAVASCRIPT. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript